# How does Android Studio Generate SHA-1 Fingerprint in Principle?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, sha1

On the internet, when comes to explaining how Android Studio generates the SHA-1 fingerprint for an app, it almost always center around just 2 messages.

(1) SHA-1 is fundamentally a checksum for your file so that the other side can check your submitted file is untampered.

(2) Where you can find your SHA-1 fingerprint on your Android Studio project.

I can understand both (1) and (2) but I have a question in between (1) and (2). When Android Studio use principle (1) to generate a SHA-1 checksum for a "file", which file is it checksum-ing against? Further, if it is checksum-ing against a particular file or a set of files, then how come after I modify my Android project a lot, the SHA-1 checksum still remains the same?

Can someone bridge the knowledge between (1) and (2) for me?

Thanks!